# How does java.util.stream.Stream.distinct() method work? Can I override the equals() method of the stream of the objects?

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct-values

My use case is that I am trying to use the `distinct` method of `Stream` to remove students with the same roll number from a list of objects of class `StudentCourseMapping`.

POJO details are below:

```java
public class StudentCourseMapping implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private Integer roll;
    private String course;
```

Below is the equals method:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        StudentCourseMapping other = (StudentCourseMapping) obj;
        if (roll == null) {
            if (other.roll != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!roll.equals(other.roll))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Below is the implementation:

```java
public class RemoveDuplicateUsingStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<StudentCourseMapping> studentCourceList = JacksonJSONReaderObjectMapper.jsonReader();
        
        studentCourceList.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
        StudentCourseMapping s0 = studentCourceList.get(0);
        StudentCourseMapping s1 = studentCourceList.get(1);
        System.out.println(s0.equals(s1));

        Set<Integer> st = new HashSet();
        List<StudentCourseMapping>studentCourceList2 = studentCourceList.stream().filter(s -> st.add(s.getRoll()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        System.out.println(studentCourceList2.size());
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
StudentCourseMapping [name=Alu, dept=Physics, roll=12, course=Quantum Theory]
StudentCourseMapping [name=Alu, dept=Physics, roll=12, course=English]
StudentCourseMapping [name=Sam, dept=Commerce, roll=16, course=English]
StudentCourseMapping [name=Sam, dept=Commerce, roll=16, course=Accounts]
StudentCourseMapping [name=Joe, dept=Arts, roll=19, course=English]
StudentCourseMapping [name=Joe, dept=Arts, roll=19, course=Hindi]
true
3
```

`JacksonJSONReaderObjectMapper.jsonReader()` is a custom method which reads the below JSON. I am able to achieve the same by using filter and adding to `HashSet` but I really want to know what is wrong with my distinct implementation.

```json
{
    "studentCourseMapping": [
        {
            "name": "Alu",
            "dept": "Physics",
            "roll": 12,
            "course": "Quantum Theory"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alu",
            "dept": "Physics",
            "roll": 12,
            "course": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "dept": "Commerce",
            "roll": 16,
            "course": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "dept": "Commerce",
            "roll": 16,
            "course": "Accounts"
        },
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "dept": "Arts",
            "roll": 19,
            "course": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "dept": "Arts",
            "roll": 19,
            "course": "Hindi"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to test the equals method directly it was working properly and returning true since both the `s0` and `s1` has roll as 12.

```java
        StudentCourseMapping s0 = studentCourceList.get(0);
        StudentCourseMapping s1 = studentCourceList.get(1);
        System.out.println(s0.equals(s1));
```

But when I am using `distinct` all the objects are getting printed and also while trying to debug in Eclipse the distinct method I wrote is not getting called, but the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) says it should be called. I am using JDK 11:

> `Stream<T> distinct()`
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to [`Object.equals(Object))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) of this stream.

Comment: Remember that when you override `equals` you always have to also override the `hashCode` to match (that is, to represent the same information).

Comment: Your class `StudentCourseMapping` should implement the `hashCode()` method as well, in accordance with [the rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for this method (i.e.: if `equals()` between two objects is `true`, then they must return the same hash code).

Comment: It breaks - in fact - because `hashCode()` has not been overwritten ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/aPjZIq)). When we override it, it works as expected ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/RzAlsc)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RealSkeptic and @Jesper have already said in the comments, you do have to override the `hashCode` method of your `StudentCourseMapping` class in order to properly compare the elements in the stream and keep only the distinct ones according to your `equals` implementation.

Although, it is not mentioned in the [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) documentation, as it is considered implied and amply covered in the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) documentation, but when overriding the `equals()` method we must also override the `hashcode()` method in order to honor the general hashcode contract.

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

In fact, your snippet produces the desired output once the `hashCode()` method is properly overridden.

```
public class StudentCourseMapping implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private Integer roll;
    private String course;

    //... your class implementation ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
        StudentCourseMapping student = (StudentCourseMapping) obj;
        return Objects.equals(roll, student.roll);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(roll);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[name = %s, dept = %s, roll = %d, course = %s]", name, dept, roll, course);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just one query that how this equals was working? System.out.println(s0.equals(s1));

Comment: @AmitSaha The equals method **does** work properly on its own. As it did in your snippet. However, this method is often used in pair with the hashCode method when storing data in hash structures such as: HashMap and HashSet, or for example, and evidently, when using particular aggregate operations like the distinct you've used above. Always assume that when something operates with the equals method might work with the hashCode method too and expect a consistent behavior according to its general contract.

Answer (score 1):

In theory your existing implementation would work since distinct implies non equal values.  But the `Stream()` implementation of `distinct()` makes use of a `LinkedHashSet` (which makes direct use of the object's `hashCode` method) to catch the duplicates. Since each class reference is unique and the default implementation of `hashCode` is based on the value of that reference, duplicates from an `equals` perspective will not be caught.

Here is a simple demo using the default `hashCode`.  A list of 10 objects is created. Then that list is repeatedly added to itself and shuffled resulting in a list of 10,240 objects, with a total of 10 distinct hashCodes.   So when the `distinct()` method checks those `hashcodes`, it will find duplicates and ignore them.

**Note:** This class uses a simple and incomplete `equals` method that is sufficient for this controlled demo.

```
class Etest {
        int v;
        
        public Etest(int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object ob) {
            return ((Etest)ob).v == this.v;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return v+"";
        }
}

List<Etest> list = new ArrayList<>(IntStream.range(1, 11)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Etest(i)).toList());

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    list.addAll(list);
}
System.out.println("Total entries = " + list.size());
list.stream().distinct().forEach(e->System.out.printf("%s ", e));
```

prints something like

```
Total entries = 10240
3 4 8 9 2 10 6 5 1 7
```